# I had Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to update to 14.10 and I get a black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: 14.04, boot, 14.10, cursor

I went to update my Ubuntu version from 14.04 to 14.10 . I got a black screen with a blinking cursor at the top left corner, while updating my computer turned off, every time i boot Ubuntu i get the following 3 messages on the top left corner and then it goes to a blinking cursor

```
*Setting up X socket directories...                                                 [OK]

*Restoring resolver state...                                                        [OK]

*speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /ect/default/speech-dispatcher                    [OK]

saned disabled; edit /ect/default/saned
```

I have an ASUS K55A running windows 8.1 with Ubuntu in dualboot.

Comment: Which display manager are you using/Did you install another display manager than the initially installed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Install another display manager

When you choose between Windows and Ubuntu at boot choose the menu entry `Ubuntu ... (recovery mode)` and in the following menu start a root terminal/shell with network. In there do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

When asked which display manager to use by default, choose `gdm`.

Another display manager will work or bring you another issue which you can investigate.

#### Check for failing driver installations

In the aforementioned root terminal run `sudo dkms autoinstall` and check that it doesn't produce any output and that it returns with `0` by running `echo $?` right after the command.

Comment: So i entered Ubuntu Recovery mode and i get the normal options, one of them being "Network   Enable Networking" I hit enter and some commands come up and I'm left to do nothing, i restart my computer by holding the power button and go back into Ubuntu recovery and I hit "Root Drop to shell prompt" and do the commands you stated and it says i can't connect to the Ubuntu archive, so help?

Comment: So your one step further encountering the next bug. The network-enabled recovery shell often works randomly only (you can retry if you have energy left; I'll finally report a bug after suffering for years from  the issue). Try `sudo service networking start && sudo service network-manager restart`. If that doesn't work you'll have to figure out how to establish an internet connection on the command line.

Comment: the command didn't work I'm trying another Ethernet way, do you know any commands i could use for Ethernet?

Comment: Try adding lines `iface eth0 inet dhcp` and `iface eth1 inet dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces` (edit with `nano` in the recovery shell) and run `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and `sudo ifconfig eth1 up` after plugging in you ethernet cable.

Comment: You're suffering from two bugs at the same time :( Establishing an internet connection from command line is an advanced, but not overly complicated topic. Do what I wrote - in the remote shell or after logging in the screen you get now - in case of problems you'll have to work through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/.

Comment: I managed to establish a connection, I do the commands I wait for about 10-15 minutes I hard reset my PC and boot into Ubuntu and I get another 2 messages "starting uuid generator uuidd........ [OK]" and "Starting NTP server ntpd........ [OK]

Comment: And that solved you problem?

Comment: No it goes away and i still get the black screen

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gdm` takes 15 minutes and hangs?

Comment: the whole process took around 15 minutes and then hangs

Comment: Okay I did your steps a couple of times and I booted into Ubuntu and a whole tonne of messages popped up this time bit no login screen, leaves my hanging with the black screen with a blinking cursor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22463/discussion-between-gregory-shiel-and-karl-richter).

Comment: Please check whether http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it solves you issues and give a feedback here.